# Best way to save an UIImage to Apple TV

Tags: ios, tvos, apple-tv

I downloaded an UIImage from server. I want to save UIImage data into Apple TV.
how can I do that. Thank you.
I mean: Is there any way to save photo into Gallery (like iPhone), or moreover, save photo to iCloud.

Comment: How are you writing the application? Native or TVML/TVJS or some combination?

Comment: I'm writing native app by using Swift

Comment: [this news article](http://9to5mac.com/2016/01/25/icloud-photo-library-apple-tv/) might be relevant. It announces what OP is looking for for the beta of tvOS 9.2

Answer (score 2):

> There is no persistent local storage for apps on Apple TV. This means
>   that every app developed for the new Apple TV must be able to store
>   data in iCloud and retrieve it in a way that provides a great customer
>   experience.

but

> You have complete access to cached and temporary directory. Just
>   remember that this data can, and will, be purged at some point.

So to access Temporary folder you have to do

```
NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSSstring stringWithFormat:@"%d", appBundleId];
```

and the Cache folder like

```
NSString *cachesPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *cacheFile = [cachesPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.plist"];
```

Source:https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19002

Answer (score -1):

In `TVML`/`TVOS` it is same as `iPhone`/`iPad` application.

only condition is for

Case 1: Image is fetching form web

```
let url = NSURL(string:"ImagePath")  
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL:url!) 
imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

Case 2: Image is store in your bundle

```
imageView?.image = UIImage(named:"ImageName")
```

Comment: I means is there any way to store image on apple Tv (such as gallery or save photo to user icloud, etc..)

Comment: This does not even try to answer the question.